# Attaching a component to the shaft of a DC motor

Tags: power-supply, motor, contact

Does anyone have any idea how to mount, say, an LED light, on top of a spinning motor shaft without getting the wires tangled?

Comment: Glue? Velcro? Tape? Screw? Rivit? RTV? Zip tie? I'm not sure how this electrical engineering or why this is a probelm. You need to define the problem a lot more or this question will get closed.

Comment: @Puffafish what I mean is that if I attach it to the top of the shaft, the cable will get tangled and stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual method for getting power and signals to a device which is spinning is to use a **slip ring**.  There are loads of kinds from huge ones down to little ones for hobbyists to experiment with, and are related to how power gets to rotors in certain kinds of motor.

Slip ring diagram:

[image]
<sup>From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring)</sup>

More exotic possibilities include:

- Some kind of wireless charging such as [qi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_(standard))
- A battery on the moving part if that is practical.
- With a stepper motor I've seen simple cables used and software to go clockwise N turns, then anticlockwise N turns to keep the cable from wrapping around
- Take power from the rotor windings, which might be very dirty DC or AC
- A generator, possibly as simple as a little coil passing a fixed magnet (if you only need a tiny amount of power)

Comment: If the shaft is large enough, it might be possible to drill a hole through it, and connect wires to one of the armature windings where they connect to the commutator. Of course it will not be smooth DC, and possibly AC, but that may be a desirable feature, so the pulsating light from the LED could be used with a photocell to measure RPM.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let the rotation of the device power the LED?

Place a coil on the rotating part, that passes quite near a magnet on a non-rotating part. Being dragged across the magnet will induce a current into the coil. Clean up that power and use it to light the LED.

If you want to selectively turn the LED on and off, then replace the magnet with an electromagnet you turn on when you want the LED on.